# What is the y value for the circle whose radius is $\frac{1}{4}$ that makes it tangent to the function $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, circles

I have seen videos explaining why the area under the curve of the graph whose equation is $y = e^{-x^2}$ is $\sqrt{\pi}$

So I thought myself we can probably inscribe circles in there since the area is related to $\pi$

So I tried this with a circle whose radius is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and started trying to find the $y$ coordinate of the circle that'd make it perfectly tangent to the graph of the function.

I tried calculating that value, but to no avail, too complicated for me.

I tried to round it using Desmos and I went on to see at which value the circle is approximately tangent to the graph of the function, and it gave me this:

[image]

A `y` value of approximately $\frac{1}{3.7168943212}$ or $0.269041$

What is the exact value that makes the circle perfectly tangent to the function?

Comment: Why not take the circle tangent to the graph at $(0,1)$? Or anywhere else? The area under the entire curve has nothing to do with this notion.

Comment: You are exactly looking for the osculating circle (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle). To find radius the osculating circle in you have to find the arc lenght parametrization of the curve $(x,e^{-x^2})$ and then compute the curvature. For the center of the osculating circle you can compute the coordinates directly through the derivatives of $e^{-x^2}$ as explained in Wikipedia. Unfortunately it is not always possible to find the arc lenght parametrization because one have to solve integrals and it isn't always possible.

Comment: The OP hasn't defined "best" in "best circle. The way I read it, they are open to circles of different radii and maybe centers. So I don't think they're explicitly looking for the osculating circle.  I read it as @FShrite did in his solution.

Comment: Please play around with $t$. When $t = 0$, you can see unit circle centered at $(0, 1/2)$ tangent to curve at a single point and then on two points owing to symmetry. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cpaohkj6oc

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary point on the curve, let $(t,e^{-t^2})$. The slope of the normal at this point is the opposite inverse of the derivative, $\dfrac{e^{t^2}}{2t}$ giving the intersection with the axis at $x=0,y=e^{-t^2}-\dfrac{e^{t^2}}2$. Hence the radius of the tangent circle, $r=\sqrt{t^2+\dfrac{e^{2t^2}}4}$.

Clearly, this relation is not analytically invertible, and if you want to choose the radius, you'll need to solve numerically.

---

It is possible to eliminate $t$ to establish a direct relation between $y$ and $r$. By solving a quadratic equation, we have

$$e^{t^2}=\pm\sqrt{y^2+2}-y$$ and

$$r=\sqrt{\log\left(\pm\sqrt{y^2+2}-y\right)+\dfrac{\left(\pm\sqrt{y^2+2}-y\right)^2}4}$$ but this brings no simplication...

Answer (score 0):

$$D_x[e^{-x^2}]=-2x\cdot e^{-x^2}$$

A circle about the origin has the implicit derivative:

$$x^2+y^2=r^2,\,2x+2y\cdot y'(x)=0,\,y'(x)=-\frac{x}{y}$$

We seek a circle $y(x)$ such that:

$$D_x[e^{-x^2}]=y'(x)$$

At some point $x$, or:

$$-2x\cdot e^{-x^2}=-\frac{x}{y}$$

Which implies the trivial solution $x=0$ or the solution:

$$y(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{x^2}$$

A circle's upper half, about the origin, may be described by $y(x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. Then we have:

$$\tag{1}r^2-x^2=\frac{1}{4}e^{2x^2}$$

But of course you wish for the circle to actually *touch* the graph at this point too, so we require also that:

$$\tag{2}r^2-x^2=e^{-2x^2},\,e^{2x^2}=\frac{1}{r^2-x^2}$$

Which must be satisfied for some $x$ for the circle to be tangential. By symmetry of the circle and the exponential, wlog $x\ge0$. Note that the trivial solution $x=0$ requires $r=1$ and this circle doesn't work as it intersects elsewhere.

Substituting $2)$ into $1)$, and multiplying by $r^2-x^2$ gives:

$$(r^2-x^2)^2=\frac{1}{4},\,r^2-x^2=\frac{1}{2},\,x=\sqrt{r^2-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Then substituting the middle equation into $1)$ we find:

$$e^{-2x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\implies-2x^2=-\ln2,\,x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\ln 2}\approx0.588705$$

And:

$$r^2-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\ln 2\implies r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{1+\ln2}\approx0.920094$$

Let's plot this to see if it really works, or if it suffers from other intersections:

[image: Graph]

There are no other intersections, so this is your desired circle. As commented, this has nothing to do with the integral being $\sqrt{\pi}$.